# Python short url generator

Tags: python, short-url

I'm using this code to generate short url. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576918/

The idea is to encode an integer id using base62 and function enbase just works fine.

```
class UrlEncoder(object):
    ...
    def enbase(self, x, min_length=0):
        result = self._enbase(x)
        padding = self.alphabet[0] * (min_length - len(result))
        return '%s%s' % (padding, result)
```

But I don't quite understand what this code is for:

```
class UrlEncoder(object):
    ...

    def encode_url(self, n, min_length=0):
        return self.enbase(self.encode(n), min_length)
    def decode_url(self, n):
        return self.decode(self.debase(n))
    def encode(self, n):
        return (n & ~self.mask) | self._encode(n & self.mask)
```

Why encode then enbase? What does that bitwise operation do?
Could someone shed some light on me? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the value of `self.mask`? Could you show the `_encode` function?

Comment: In here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576918/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the whole code: The net effect of `encode()` is to apply `_encode()` to the least-significant `self.block_size`-many bits of the value. `_encode()` appears to reverse those bits. It seems to be just a bit of additional scrambling. The documentation below the code explains why they are doing all these extra shuffles.

Comment: > The documentation below the code explains why they are doing all these extra shuffles.

+1